# Maximal orders in Clifford algebras

Tags: reference-request, continued-fractions, clifford-algebras

Let
$$
\mathcal{C}_n(R)=R\langle e_1,\ldots,e_n\rangle/(\{e_i^2+1\}, \{e_ie_j+e_je_i:i\neq j\})
$$
be the Clifford algebra for the negative definite quadratic form $-\sum_ix_i^2$ obtained by adjoining $n$ anti-commuting square roots of -1.

My question is:  What are the maximal orders of $\mathcal{C}_n(\mathbb{Q})$ containing $\mathcal{C}_n(\mathbb{Z})$?

The only ramified prime is 2, so the only denominators appearing will be powers of 2, e.g. the Hurwitz quaternions
$$
\mathcal{C}_2(\mathbb{Z})\cup\left(\mathcal{C}_2(\mathbb{Z})+\frac{1}{2}\left(1+e_1+e_2+e_1e_2\right)\right)
$$
are the unique maximal order in $\mathcal{C}_2(\mathbb{Q})$.

I thought I'd be able to find a reference with some combinatorial description, what powers of two go where, but came up empty-handed.

This is repeat of an unanswered question [Orders of Clifford algebra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/185541/orders-of-clifford-algebra), but I thought I'd ask again.

My research interest in the question (besides it being nice to know) is whether the restriction of these lattices to the $(n+1)$-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\cong\langle1,e_1,\ldots, e_n\rangle_{\mathbb{R}}\subseteq\mathcal{C}_n(\mathbb{R})$ are ever dense enough for my purposes (do open unit balls around the lattice points cover $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$?).  [They clearly are for $n=0$, $1$, $2$, and $3$, but I couldn't get past that.]

Comment: Why "continued-fractions"?

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov While the question itself has nothing to with continued fractions, the "application" I have in mind is approximating points in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ by quotients $pq^{-1}$ of "integers" in the maximal order using nearest integer continued fractions.