# Norm-Euclidean octonionic orders

Tags: nt.number-theory

*Short version:* Besides the Cayley integers and the basic reflections thereof, are there any other known norm-Euclidean $\mathbb{Z}$-orders in the octonions?

*Long version:* I'm looking at higher-dimensional generalizations of rings of integers for imaginary quadratic fields, due to their connection to continued fractions. It is known that there are five imaginary cases that are norm-Euclidean:
$$
\mathbb{Z}[i], \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}i], \mathbb{Z}\left[ \frac{1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\right], \mathbb{Z}\left[ \frac{1+\sqrt{7}i}{2}\right], \mathbb{Z}\left[ \frac{1+\sqrt{11}i}{2}\right].
$$

In the quaternions, it is known that there are only three $\mathbb{Z}$-orders in totally definite quaternion algebras that are norm-Euclidean, up to reflection. (I found the explicit descriptions of the orders in "Norm Euclidean Quaternionic Orders" by Robert W. Fitzgerald, and the fact that there were only these three was mentioned in "Euclidean totally definite quaternion fields over the rational field and over quadratic number fields" by Jean-Paul Cerri, Jérôme Chaubert, and Pierre Lezowski.) Also, although all the examples below come from specific quaternion algebras, I want to visualize them as all living inside $\mathbb{H}\cong \mathbb{R}^4$ so I will break with convention and always have $i^2=j^2=k^2=-1$.

From the quaternion algebra $\left( \frac{-1,-1}{\mathbb{Q}}\right)$, the Hurwitz integers, given by
$$
\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}i \oplus \mathbb{Z}j \oplus \mathbb{Z}\frac{1+i+j+k}{2},
$$
are norm-Euclidean.

From the quaternion algebra $\left( \frac{-1,-3}{\mathbb{Q}}\right)$, the Gausenstein integers, given by
$$
\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2}\oplus \mathbb{Z}j\oplus \mathbb{Z}\frac{-j+\sqrt{3}k}{2},
$$
are norm-Euclidean.

And from the quaternion algebra $\left( \frac{-2,-5}{\mathbb{Q}}\right)$, the order given by
$$
\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}\frac{2+\sqrt{2}i-\sqrt{10}k}{4}\oplus \mathbb{Z}\frac{2+3\sqrt{2}i+\sqrt{10}k}{4} \oplus \mathbb{Z}\frac{1+\sqrt{2}i+\sqrt{5}j}{2}
$$
is norm-Euclidean.

So the question seems completely solved in this case. It should be noted that if one builds an order in an algebra over a different field (for example $\left(\frac{-1,-1}{\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{5}]}\right)$), one could find other norm-Euclidean examples, but these will not form $\mathbb{Z}$-orders and so not be useful in the applications I am looking at.

In the octonions, however, I have not been able to find any references to anything beyond the Cayley integers, which are known to be norm-Euclidean. Are there any other norm-Euclidean $\mathbb{Z}$-orders out there in the octonions?

*Supplemental question:* norm-Euclidean-ness in this case can be defined by saying that every point in the Voronoi region around the origin has distance strictly less than $1$ to the origin. What if this restriction is relaxed from "strictly less" to "less than or equal to"?  In the complex case, this allows $\mathbb{Z}(1+i)\oplus \mathbb{Z}(1-i)$*, and in the quaternionic case, this allows
$$
\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}i\oplus \mathbb{Z}j\oplus\mathbb{Z}k.
$$
What other new orders are possible?

*This is a weird example as it is a lattice but not technically an order as it lacks the multiplicative identity, but for the applications I'm looking at, that's fine.

Comment: Related question: [https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347994/maximal-orders-in-clifford-algebras]

Also, for your supplement, the non-maximal order $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ also hits the boundary.